# how to insert array into mysql after get the post data by for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I just learned how to Foreach value from POST from form:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
}
```

But my question is how to insert those data: $key $value to the mysql database.Can I just do like this :

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tableName $key $value)
```

Comment: you have to see with `INSERT BATCH` for this.

Comment: is your `$key` equivalent to your SQL column name?

Comment: yes,my $key equivalent to my SQL column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Not sure how you handled your sql connexion, so I wrote a short example
$linkDB=new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'db_name');
if($connectDB->connect_error) {
    die('Erreur de connexion ('.$connectDB->connect_errno.'): '.$linkDB->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$linkDB->set_charset('utf-8');

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    /* Just to be safe, I suggest to manually escape the key,
     * to avoid injections. Someone correct me if it's wrong.
     */
    $key=mysqli_real_escape_string($linkDB, $key);
    $stmt=$linkDB->prepare(/** @lang MySQL */
        "INSERT INTO `tablename` (`$key`)
        VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
    if($stmt !== false) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$linkDB->close();
```

In case you want to use all key/values in the post in one query, then do like this instead.

```
$queryCols="";
$queryVals="";
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $queryCols.="`".mysqli_real_escape_string($linkDB, $key)."`,";
    $queryVals.="'".mysqli_real_escape_string($linkDB, $value)."',";
}
$queryCols=preg_replace("/(,)$/", "", $queryCols);
$queryVals=preg_replace("/(,)$/", "", $queryVals);
$stmt=$linkDB->prepare(/** @lang MySQL */
    "INSERT INTO `tablename` ($queryCols)
    VALUES ($queryVals)");
if($stmt !== false) {
    $stmt->execute;
}
$stmt->close();
$linkDB->close();
```

Something like this should do the trick... ;)

Comment: Thank you very much !I'll try!

Answer (score 1):

Create the sql insert query from array values,See the below Example

```
$ins_clm = "";
$ins_val = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
   $ins_clm .= $key.","; 
   $ins_val .= "'".$value."',";


}
   $ins_clm = substr($ins_clm ,0,strlen($ins_clm )-1);
   $ins_val = substr($ins_val ,0,strlen($ins_val )-1);

  $ins_query = "insert into table ($ins_clm) values ($ins_val)";


   $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$ins_query);
```